# Return a list after append() and reverse()

Tags: python, list, recursion, append, reverse

I'm new at **python (2.7.3)** and I'm trying to write a program that **converts a given decimal number into a binary one**.
To that end, I wrote a function that takes the decimal number and an empty list, divides the number by 2 appends the rest to the list and repeats the function with the remaining quotient until the quotient is 0.

```
def convert_to_bin(dec_num,list):
    quo = dec_num/2 # val is the quotient when dividing by 2
    rest = dec_num%2 # rest is the rest when dividing by 2
    list.append(rest)
    if (quo==0):
        list.reverse()
        print list
        return list
    else:
        convert_to_bin(quo,list)
bin_list = [] # initialize list for binary entries
dec_num = 83 # decimal number that is to be converted into binary       
bin_list = convert_to_bin(dec_num,bin_list)
print bin_list
```

The function works all right so far, I just can't find a way to actually **return the list after calling the function** - instead I always get **"None" as a return statement**.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name; you are masking the built-in type.

Comment: probably you're looking for this `bin_list = map(int,bin(dec_num)[2:])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return the result of the recursive call:

```
else:
    return convert_to_bin(quo,list)
```

A recursive call returns to the *caller*, not the top-level frame. So a `convert_to_bin()` function calling `convert_to_bin()` *again* was ignoring the return value from the nested call, instead then returning `None` as the end of function is reached.

Comment: I KNEW it was a complete beginner's mistake! Thank you.